# `bash -c` followed by an option command creates a duplicate process

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, command-line

Running

```
bash -c "set -o vi; tail -F foo.txt"
```

creates a duplicate process:

```
 -> ps -ef | grep foo.txt
zsilver+  11762  91505  0 12:38 pts/28   00:00:00 bash -c set -o vi; tail -F foo.txt
zsilver+  11763  11762  0 12:38 pts/28   00:00:00 tail -F foo.txt
zsilver+  13026  92735  0 12:39 pts/60   00:00:00 grep --color=auto foo.txt
```

However, if I omit the `set -o vi`:

```
bash -c "tail -F foo.txt"
```

only one shows up:

```
 -> ps -ef | grep foo.txt
zsilver+  14787  91505  0 12:40 pts/28   00:00:00 tail -F foo.txt
zsilver+  14822  92735  0 12:40 pts/60   00:00:00 grep --color=auto foo.txt
```

Does this mean there's actually two instances of `tail -F foo.txt` running? If so, how can I avoid that when I specifically want to `set -o pipefail` within the command argument to `bash -c '...'`?

Comment: No, there isn't an extra `tail`. You just lose an optimization that forces an automatic `exec` in the simplest case.

Comment: The process name is the first one (e.g. bash, tail, grep) and you have one of each, the following are command line arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How To Read `ps`

```
 -> ps -ef | grep foo.txt
zsilver+  11762  91505  0 12:38 pts/28   00:00:00 bash -c set -o vi; tail -F foo.txt
zsilver+  11763  11762  0 12:38 pts/28   00:00:00 tail -F foo.txt
zsilver+  13026  92735  0 12:39 pts/60   00:00:00 grep --color=auto foo.txt
```

...shows three processes running:

- bash
- tail
- grep

This is exactly what you'd expect for `bash -c 'tail -F foo.txt'` when running at the same time as `grep`. There's only *one* copy of each of those three programs; `set -o vi; tail -F foo.txt` is just an argument to `bash`, not a separate program. (And it is, to emphasize, *only one* argument; on many platforms, including the one where the above output was generated, `ps` output doesn't generate shell quoting to accurately reflect argument boundaries).

---

#### Why

Bash sometimes, when it's *very* certain that doing so won't cause any unintended side effects, adds an implicit `exec` to a command executed by `bash -c 'something'`, making it act like `bash -c 'exec something'`.

The `exec` builtin makes the shell replace itself with the target executable (such that the shell is no longer in memory and no longer shows up in `ps`), instead of forking off a subshell and having *that forked subshell* replace itself with the target executable. This replacement is only correct if the shell has nothing to do after the target executable finishes -- has no signal-handling traps that might need to be handled, has no temporary files it might need to clean up, and is otherwise in a maximally-simple configuration.

When you change a noninteractive shell from its default state, it can reasonably choose to decide that it's no longer safe to apply optimizations that were developed only to be safe in the most trivial cases. (Exactly when bash applies this optimization is implementation-defined, but it's obligated not to apply it in any circumstance where doing so would cause it to no longer provide documented semantics).

---

In the case of `set -o pipefail` in particular, bash *needs* to stay in-memory so it can check the exit status of all the components of a pipeline and use that result to set its own exit status. Because it can't just exit with the exit status of the last pipeline component, it can no longer `exec` that component after pipeline setup is complete. That's not true for `set -o vi`, *but* the easiest thing for a shell author is just to avoid the optimization when *any* setting has been changed, instead of needing to maintain a list of which settings do or don't make the optimization unsafe.

Because the shell is just `wait()`ing for the pipeline components to complete, checking the exit status returned by `waitpid()`, and then `exit()`ing itself, its overhead is almost negligible; the only significant cost you're paying is the `fork()` that would have been avoided if a direct `exec()` had been possible.